# TestNG: How to rerun testng suite based on number of rows in Excel file

Tags: java, excel, testng, test-suite

I have a Testng suite consisting of 3 java classes which are for automating 3 different pages of a mobile application:

**Class 1** (this is about registration & imports the data from excelsheet into String array. Then the data is entered on page 1 of the application. The AndroidDriver is also initialized in this class.)

**Class 2** extends Class 1 (this is about payment)

**Class 3** (final page about review. There is a button to go back to Page 1 registration to start a new order)

Now what I want to do is continue running the suite based on the number of rows populated in the excelsheet.

The order of execution should be:

1. Import row 1 from XLS => Class 1 -> Class 2 -> Class 3 (if another
   row exists then)
2. Import row 2 from XLS => Class 1 -> Class 2 ->
   Class 3 (if another row exists then)
3. Import row 3 from XLS => Class
   1 -> Class 2 -> Class 3 (end test because there are no more rows)

How can I achieve this? I have been reading about DataProvider & Factories but I have never used them & all the other posts seem to suggest that this problem can only be solved through the use of them. I am using a single driver instance which is being inherited by class 2 & 3. I have incorporated Apache POI library in my test for reading data from XLSX file storing it in the array successfully.

**UPDATE**
Is this code correct?

```
public class WebTestFactory {
  @Factory
  public Object[] createInstances() {
   Object[] result = new Object[number of rows]; 
   for (int m = 0; m < number of rows; m++) {
      result[m] = m;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
@Factory
public static Object[] createTests() {
    List<Object> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    Rows rows = // your POI rows
    for (Row row : rows) {
        tests.add(new Class1Test(row));
        tests.add(new Class2Test(row));
        tests.add(new Class3Test(row));
    }
    return tests.toArray();
}
```

This will create the desired test class instances for each row and queue them for execution by TestNG.

You can use factories with data providers as well. See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories for details.

Comment: I have updated my original post with a code. Could you please check it? My main concern is not passing the entire row but the 'number of rows'. For example if there are 5 rows in the excelsheet then i = 5.